# NotFound exception creating Solr cores on installation

Tags: solr, sitecore-install-framework, installation, sitecore-install-assistant

I've installed Solr 7.5 successfully. I am using SIA (`Sitecore Install Assistant`) for my installing Sitecore 9.2.0.

I am getting exception "NotFound - https://solr75:8750/solr//admin/cores?action=Create&name=sc92_xdb&property.update.autoCreateFields=false&wt=json"

## Log file:

```
[------------- XConnectSolr_CleanCores : EnsurePath --------------------------]
[XConnectSolr_CleanCores]:[Clean] D:\Solr75\Solr-7.5.0\server\solr\sc92_xdb
[XConnectSolr_CleanCores]:[Clean] D:\Solr75\Solr-7.5.0\server\solr\sc92_xdb_rebuild
[XConnectSolr_CleanCores]:[Create] D:\Solr75\Solr-7.5.0\server\solr\sc92_xdb
[XConnectSolr_CleanCores]:[Create] D:\Solr75\Solr-7.5.0\server\solr\sc92_xdb_rebuild

[------- XConnectSolr_PrepareCores [1] : Copy --------------------------------]
[XConnectSolr_PrepareCores [1]]:[Copying] D:\Solr75\Solr-7.5.0\server\solr\configsets\_default\* => D:\Solr75\Solr-7.5.0\server\solr\sc92_xdb

[------- XConnectSolr_PrepareCores [2] : Copy --------------------------------]
[XConnectSolr_PrepareCores [2]]:[Copying] D:\Solr75\Solr-7.5.0\server\solr\configsets\_default\* => D:\Solr75\Solr-7.5.0\server\solr\sc92_xdb_rebuild

[-------------- XConnectSolr_StartSolr : ManageService -----------------------]
[XConnectSolr_StartSolr]:[Updating] Solr-7.5.0

[-------- XConnectSolr_CreateCores [1] : ManageSolrCore ----------------------]
[XConnectSolr_CreateCores [1]]:[Requesting] https://solr75:8750/solr/
[XConnectSolr_CreateCores [1]]:[SolrCore] Performing Create on https://solr75:8750/solr/

NotFound - https://solr75:8750/solr//admin/cores?action=Create&name=sc92_xdb&property.update.autoCreateFields=false&wt=json
[TIME] 00:00:52
NotFound - https://solr75:8750/solr//admin/cores?action=Create&name=sc92_xdb&property.update.autoCreateFields=false&wt=json
```

[image]
Please assist, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr service URL is specified wrongly. Based on error log where you have duplicated "//" in the path, I assume you have specified your Solr service URL like this `https://solr75:8750/solr/`.

Correct value is without `/` at the end.

Change your Solr service URL to this value instead `https://solr75:8750/solr`